# Customized output from wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to get the output from my WCF Service as
{"taskList":[{"oid":"30774","Id":"4122"}]}

While i am getting output as
[{"Key":"taskList","Value":[{"oid":"30774","Id":"4122"}]}]

My code is as

```html
 public Dictionary<string, List<JobModel>> getList(Job jobList)
  {
    Dictionary<string, List<JobModel>> dataDict = new Dictionary<string, List<JobModel>>();
    dataDict.Add("taskList", jobList);
    string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataDict.Values);
    return dataDict;
  }
```

Any idea how can i achieve the goal.

Comment: Create a taskList object with oid and Id properties or whatever properties you need. Instantiate and populate that, then serial it to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a dictionary, simply add `jobList` to a new anonymous object with a property called `taskList` as the root element (assuming `jobList` is really a `List<JobModel>`):

```
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { taskList = jobList });
```

Which will output `{"taskList":[{"oid":"30774","Id":"4122"}]}`.

Obviously you also want your WCF service to return this string value, not the dictionary itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am getting response with extra backslases and double quotes. Guide me please. "{\"taskList\":[{\"oid\":\"30774\",\"Id\":\"4122\"}]}

Comment: are you seeing that in the debugger? that's normal. the `\` is a escape character. try printing it to the console.

Comment: Its not in the debugger. I have called the service in the chrome explorer and got output there.

Comment: @MusaabZeeshan it could be possible that the service is trying to re-serialize the string, hence adding the backslashes. Instead of returning a string, try changing the return type to `ExpandObject` and just return `new { taskList = jobList };`, see if that changes anything.

Comment: Hi Dear  PoweredByOrange, Many thanks for your time. I've followed your instruction but unfortunatelyj  i am getting the following error. "cannot implicitly convert anonymous type #1 to system.dynamic.expandoobject". I have looked over internet but couldnot found any help regarding this error.

Comment: try changing the return type to just `object`?